# Redis - Turn all masters to masters and slaves manually

Tags: redis

I have a redis cluster consisting of 6 masters and I want to turn it to 3 masters and 3 slaves manually.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the redis first and then switch the master/slave.

Stop slave redis:
`[root@localhost redis-2.8.3]# src/redis-cli -n 6379 shutdown`

Update slave redis.conf (add slaveof xxx.xx.xx.xx[master ip]  yyyy[master port])

`slaveof 192.168.10.1 6379`

Start slave redis:
`[root@localhost redis-2.8.3]# src/redis-cli -p 6380`

Alos, you can set salve to master:

`[root@localhost redis-2.8.3]# src/redis-cli -p 6380 slaveof NO ONE`